# shtml pages are not working in iis7

Tags: iis-7

shtml pages are not displayed in iis7.

i get the following error when tried to access shtm file

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

pls help

-Vivek

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is tagged SSL, as shtml has nothing in common with SSL! Anyway, this is totally by design, IIS6 and later will no serve unregistered file types. More info here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326965

Comment: I removed the SSL tag.